# What is the default code of "ic_launcher_foreground.xml","ic_launcher_background.xml"and "ic_launcher_round" files in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-drawable

Idk how [those three files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoNW9.jpg) were edited... I need someone to help me out with the default code of them...

Comment: Create a new project and check out resources in there.

Comment: @Eugen_Pechanec same problem... They are empty

Answer (score 0):

The template files are located here:

```
<Android-Studio-Directory>\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\res
```

If you can't find the correct files here then [download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) again.

Answer (score 0):

Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces adaptive launcher icons, which can display a variety of shapes across different device models. For example, an adaptive launcher icon can display a circular shape on one OEM device, and display a squircle on another device. Each device OEM provides a mask, which the system then uses to render all adaptive icons with the same shape. Adaptive launcher icons are also used in shortcuts, the Settings app, sharing dialogs, and the overview screen.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Answer (score 0):

You can find the default color by click on ic_launcher_background.xml
and then go to 8th line

```
<path
    android:fillColor="#008577"
    android:pathData="M0,0h200v200h-200z" />
```

so the default color is

```
#008577
```